# User Control problem

Tags: c#, silverlight, user-controls

I want to create my own DataGrid control. Add my project User Control and
derive it from DataGrid but it gives and error in buid.

DataGridControl.xaml.cs :
    public partial class DataGridControl : **DataGrid**
    {
       ...some codes
    }

Error :  Partial declarations of 'DataGridControl' must not specify different base classes ..   DataGridControl.g.i.cs

I change this row **public partial class DataGridControl : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl** to
**public partial class DataGridControl : System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid** 
in DataGridControl.g.i.cs file but it back againg automatically.

How can I solve this problem please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [DataGrid reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28VS.95%29.aspx), you can see that it's inheriting from Control and not UserControl, that's why you can't make it the way you wanted.

What you can do however, is to create a Custom Control, which is just a C# class extending DataGrid. You can then add that to your layout using a XAML namespace include, template using the default DataGrid template as a starting point and implement all the custom functionality you want in your custom class.

For more info see this tutorial: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Creating-a-Silverlight-Custom-Control-The-Basics.aspx